# Crowd installation error

Tags: java, single-sign-on, atlassian-crowd

I was trying to install crowd. I am not able to install it as it doesn't initiate the process ( I cannot open `http://crowd.mydomain.com:8095/crowd` ), it gives me a blank screen.

Here is the log from `/var/crowd-home/atlassian-crowd.log`

```
014-06-09 21:28:16,971 localhost-startStop-1 INFO [ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/crowd]] No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
2014-06-09 21:28:25,917 localhost-startStop-1 INFO [com.atlassian.crowd.startup] System Information:
2014-06-09 21:28:25,917 localhost-startStop-1 INFO [com.atlassian.crowd.startup]        Timezone: Coordinated Universal Time
2014-06-09 21:28:25,917 localhost-startStop-1 INFO [com.atlassian.crowd.startup]        Java Version: 1.7.0_51
2014-06-09 21:28:25,918 localhost-startStop-1 INFO [com.atlassian.crowd.startup]        Java Vendor: Oracle Corporation
2014-06-09 21:28:25,918 localhost-startStop-1 INFO [com.atlassian.crowd.startup]        JVM Version: 24.51-b03
2014-06-09 21:28:25,918 localhost-startStop-1 INFO [com.atlassian.crowd.startup]        JVM Vendor: Oracle Corporation
2014-06-09 21:28:25,918 localhost-startStop-1 INFO [com.atlassian.crowd.startup]        JVM Runtime: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
2014-06-09 21:28:25,918 localhost-startStop-1 INFO [com.atlassian.crowd.startup]        Username: root
2014-06-09 21:28:25,918 localhost-startStop-1 INFO [com.atlassian.crowd.startup]        Operating System: Linux3.13.0-24-generic
2014-06-09 21:28:25,918 localhost-startStop-1 INFO [com.atlassian.crowd.startup]        Architecture: amd64
2014-06-09 21:28:25,918 localhost-startStop-1 INFO [com.atlassian.crowd.startup]        File Encoding: UTF-8
2014-06-09 21:28:25,918 localhost-startStop-1 INFO [com.atlassian.crowd.startup] JVM Statistics:
2014-06-09 21:28:25,919 localhost-startStop-1 INFO [com.atlassian.crowd.startup]        Total Memory: 123MB
2014-06-09 21:28:25,919 localhost-startStop-1 INFO [com.atlassian.crowd.startup]        Used Memory: 60MB
2014-06-09 21:28:25,919 localhost-startStop-1 INFO [com.atlassian.crowd.startup]        Free Memory: 63MB
2014-06-09 21:28:25,919 localhost-startStop-1 INFO [com.atlassian.crowd.startup] Runtime Information:
2014-06-09 21:28:25,919 localhost-startStop-1 INFO [com.atlassian.crowd.startup]        Version: 2.7.2
2014-06-09 21:28:25,919 localhost-startStop-1 INFO [com.atlassian.crowd.startup]        Build Number: 626

2014-06-09 21:28:25,919 localhost-startStop-1 INFO [com.atlassian.crowd.startup]        Build Date: 2014-05-13

2014-06-09 21:28:25,919 localhost-startStop-1 INFO [crowd.console.listener.StartupListener] Upgrades not performed since the application has not been setup yet.

2014-06-09 21:28:26,063 localhost-startStop-1 INFO [ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/crowd]] org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter INFO: loaded (conf ok)

2014-06-09 21:29:11,327 localhost-startStop-1 INFO [ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/crowd]] org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter INFO: destroy called

2014-06-09 21:29:11,590 localhost-startStop-1 INFO [com.atlassian.crowd.startup] Stopping Crowd
```

Comment: Is this a valid URL: `http://:8095/crowd` ?

Comment: Yes, I am using a correct url. http://crowd.mydomain.com:8095/crowd

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly same problem and reason was that there was already a running instance. Just shut it down and restart.